# How to validate the value of an input field using mootools (value must be 8)

Tags: mootools

hope someone can give me a hint...

I have to work with mootools and have a form. One of the input fields is just valid if the value is the number 8. Does anyone has an idea how i could do this?

Best regards,
Dan

Comment: see documentation on mootools site [link](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post the html of that input I can help better. Otherwise:

```
var element = document.getElement('input');
//or 
var element = $('inputID');
//or
var element = document.querySelector('input');
```

Then use

`element.value == 8` or `element.get('value') == 8`

You can check here also the [**Mootools docs**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aget)

---

As @dimitar pointed out and I didn't mention, you need to listen for the submit of the form and then use this the code to check the input value.

Example:

```
var form = $('myForm');

form.addEvent('submit', function (e) {    // attach event to the form
    e.stop();                             // prevent it from being submited
    var input = this.getElement('input'); // get the input element
    if (input.value != 8) {               // verify the value
        alert('The value is not 8');      // inform the user
        return false;                     // end the function
    } else this.submit();                 // otherwise, continue the submit
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb57M/)

Comment: presumably he'd need a form event handler etc where to instantiate the validation from.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, you are right. I was a bit unclear. Added more to the answer now. Thanks

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for these niputs, i'll have a look at.

Comment: i use joomla-cms with contact_enhanced_extension and try to add a custom validation. the custom validation looks like this at the moment:

Comment: validate['required','length[1, -1]','digit'] it validates that just one digit is entered, now it also needs to validate that this digit is 8.

Comment: Hi, was working with the code from sergio => thanks a lot, it is working!

Comment: @bastler, nice it worked for you! if you want you can click to accept the answer

Comment: ... just trying to find out where... moment